# Optional taxonomy in cpt permalink

Tags: custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I found a ton of articles / or third party plugins that make it possible to add a taxonomy in a cpt permalink, this works fine. But I can’t find anything on how to handle cpt permalinks if no taxonomy is set.

With the taxonomy set I get custom-post-type/tax-name/post-name, but if it’s not set I keep getting custom-post-type/%tax-name%/post-name. I’m sure this can be fixed, but I don’t seem to be able to do so.

The code from [this article](https://crunchify.com/how-to-add-custom-taxonomy-in-custom-post-type-permalink/) works fine, I tried in step 4 to simple add this.

```
if ( $terms ) {
return str_replace( ‘%tourist%’ , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
} else {
return str_replace( ” , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
}
```

This results in a 404 when I try to access custom-post-type/post-name. I guess this is because the rewrite in step 2 is set to:

`‘rewrite’ => array(‘slug’ => ‘attraction/%tax-name%’)`

So in my mind the ‘rewrite’ would need to be set dynamically based on whether or not a taxonomy exists for a post, but I have no idea how to do this. Assuming that’s the way to fix this.

Anyone any suggestions how to best deal with this?

Comment: To be honest, that `%tourist%` can be replaced with anything, like `all-tourists`. I.e. Use a non-existent term, but you can just create that term in your taxonomy, if you want to, and optionally make it the default term in that taxonomy.

Comment: The problem is that not all posts are assigned to a term, and in my case it doesn't make sense to do so either. And this makes it complicated, at least I have no idea how to fix it. Some permalink should be post-type/title while others should be post-type/term/title. The last one I get to work, but then the first one breaks :S

Comment: If you don't want to use a fake/default term, then you can add custom rewrite rules which handle the other permalink structure (`/attraction/<post slug>`). See [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/) for details and examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that the issue is caused by the fact that the rewrite rule is set to include the %tax-name% placeholder even when a taxonomy is not set for the post.

One way to dynamically set the rewrite rule based on whether a taxonomy is set or not is to use the post_type_link filter. This filter allows you to modify the permalink for a post based on the post object.

Here's an example of how you could modify the rewrite rule to exclude the %tax-name% placeholder when no taxonomy is set:

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'custom_post_type_permalink', 10, 2 );
function custom_post_type_permalink( $permalink, $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_type === 'your-custom-post-type' ) {
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post, 'your-taxonomy' );
        if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
            $term = array_pop( $terms );
            $permalink = str_replace( '%your-taxonomy%', $term->slug, $permalink );
        } else {
            $permalink = str_replace( '%your-taxonomy%/', '', $permalink );
        }
    }
    return $permalink;
}
```

In this example, the post_type_link filter is used to modify the permalink for the custom post type. If a taxonomy is set for the post, the %your-taxonomy% placeholder in the rewrite rule is replaced with the slug of the first term for that taxonomy. If no taxonomy is set, the %your-taxonomy%/ part is removed from the rewrite rule, effectively removing the taxonomy from the permalink.

Comment: Thanks, this works great :)